# AWS lambda function times out invoked from aws java sdk V2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have created a AWS lambda function (written in python) that reads a tar.gz file from one S3 bucket, unzips and untars it and writes the extracted files to another S3 bucket. Tar inside the GZ is of >1GB size so lambda takes more time to complete the task.
I invoke this lambda function from a java client. I am using AWS SDK V2 for Java (software.amazon.awssdk.*), and using Lambda sync client `software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient`.

Though the lambda invocation works (`lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest)`), but it fails with "Read timed out" error. In the background (in AWS) the lambda completes its execution after sometime.

Following is the lambda client bean creation code.

```
LambdaClient lambdaClient = LambdaClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .overrideConfiguration(ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                        .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                        .build()
                )
                .build();
```

Following is the lambda invocation code.

```
//This is a user defined pojo object that maps to lambda input json payload
UntarLambdaPayload untarLambdaPayload = UntarLambdaPayload.builder()
                .sourceBucket(lambdaProps.getSourceBucket())
                .destinationBucket(lambdaProps.getDestinationBucket())
                .sourceKey("myTarFile.tar.gz")
                .build();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonRequest = mapper.writeValueAsString(untarLambdaPayload);
SdkBytes payload = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(jsonRequest);
            
InvokeRequest invokeRequest = InvokeRequest.builder()
                    .functionName(lambdaProps.getFunctionName())
                    .overrideConfiguration(AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                            .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                            .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(30)).build())
                    .payload(payload)
                    .build();
            
InvokeResponse res = lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest);
```

And I am getting the below exception.

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:102)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:204)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:83)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:167)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:175)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.DefaultLambdaClient.invoke(DefaultLambdaClient.java:2355)
```

My code's further logic depends on the successful completion of the lambda function. If lambda is timed out then code cannot proceed with processing the untarred files in S3 bucket#2.

I tried `overrideConfiguration` with apiCallTimeout and apiCallAttemptTimeout in InvokeRequest (as well as in Lambda Client), but it did not work. I am going to do research on LambdaClient waiter functionality for which I haven't got any help so far on how to use it with Lambda.

**How can I make the `lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest)` wait until the lambda running in AWS completes its execution?**

Comment: What if you put the `overrideConfiguation` into the code when you create the client, not the `InvokeRequest`?  I thought it was tied to the client.

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention that I had already added overrideConfiguration during Lambda client bean creation. But was still getting timeout.

`LambdaClient awsLambda = LambdaClient.builder()
          .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .region(lambdaProps.getRegion())
                .overrideConfiguration(ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                  .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                  .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                        .build()
                )
                .build();`

Comment: Problem solved. Answer is in this thread.
[https://repost.aws/questions/QUl5o0_uvrSWSCy0Qiz6s8wQ/aws-lambda-function-times-out-invoked-from-aws-java-sdk-v-2](https://repost.aws/questions/QUl5o0_uvrSWSCy0Qiz6s8wQ/aws-lambda-function-times-out-invoked-from-aws-java-sdk-v-2)